# Error Checking PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on expanding my PHP skills and I'm trying to write a simple program that calculates volume and checks to make sure all the numerical values are from 0-20, but for some reason I can't get my program to recognize incorrect numbers.

```
    <?php

//read deep end
$deepEnd = $_POST['deepEnd'];

//read shallow end
$shallowEnd = $_POST['shallowEnd'];

     //read length
$length = $_POST['length'];

//read width
$width = $_POST['width'];

$flag = false;
$min = 0;
$max = 20;

if($deepEnd < $min && $deepEnd > $max){
        $flag = true;
}
if($shallowEnd < $min && $shallowEnd > $max){
        $flag = true;
    }
if($length < $min && $length > $max){
        $flag = true;
}
if($width < $min && $width > $max){
         $flag = true;
 }

$volume = 0.5*($deepEnd+$shallowEnd)*$length*$width*7.5;

echo "<h2>Volume Calculator</h2>";

if($flag == 'true'){
        echo "<p>Incorrect value input. Please enter 0-20.</p>\n";
} else {
        echo "<p>Your volume is: ".$volume."  gallons.</p>\n";
}
?>
```

My input is being taken from my HTML program. The `<input type='number'>` so I'm confused why my if statements aren't interpreting it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing each variable if it is **less than `$min`** and **more than `$max`**. Unless your `$min` is greater than `$max`, your code wouldn't work.

Example:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 10;
$x = 5;
if ($x < $min && $x > $max) { // this will always evaluate as false
    // won't execute here
}
```

To solve your problem, which is to check if the value is out of scope of the `$min` or `$max`, you should use the `||` operator.

Example:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 10;
$x = -5;
if ($x < $min || $x > $max) { // true
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Isn't this what I want to find out though? I need to check to make sure those variables aren't out of the scope of my minimum value and maximum value.

Comment: @WagsPG Please explain your problem in **detail**. E.g put examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your logic is wrong, in the first check:-

```
if($deepEnd < $min && $deepEnd > $max){
        $flag = true;
}
```

this will only return error if the $deepend is less than the min and greater than the max which could never really happen, testing your code :-

```
if($deepEnd < $min OR $deepEnd > $max){
        $flag = true;
}
```

worked for me